# Wait until user input (mouse double click on image) - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make pause in app until user double click on image VB.NET. Any idea how to solve it.

Comment: try to add what you tried so far and why it is not working. question lacks a bit of details

Comment: Without more info I suggest you look into system threading within the double click event.

Comment: Simplest way: put your picture box in a modal form and close it on double click on it.